# SymPy: evaluate sum of sum

Tags: python-2.7, sympy

I need to evaluate the expression using SymPy:

[image]

I expect to obtain something like

[image]

The problem is the code

```
import sympy as sy

n,i,j = sy.symbols('n i j', integer=True)
a = sy.Function('a')

print sy.Sum(sy.Sum(a(j), (j,1,i)), (i, 1, n)).doit()
```

prints just the double sum

```
Sum(a(j), (j, 1, i), (i, 1, n))
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer you are trying to obtain is not correct. The inner summation variable is j, which is used in a(j), so the inner sum can't be computed further, and, i is the upper limit of the inner sum, so the outer sum can't be computed further either.

The summation that gives the answer you want is `Sum(a(i), (j,i,n), (i, 1, n))`, i.e.,

```
  n     n
 ___   ___
 ╲     ╲
  ╲     ╲   a(i)
  ╱     ╱
 ╱     ╱
 ‾‾‾   ‾‾‾
i = 1 j = i
```

which SymPy computes if you call `doit()`. By the way, note that you can create a double sum with a single call to Sum, by passing the outer limits as further arguments.